# How to initialize my array before accessing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The code was working before I made it into a function so I am trying to figure out what is the difference and how to fix it.

```
import React from 'react';

const Ninjas = ({list}) => {

    
    const ninjaList = list.map( ninjan => {
        return (
            <div className="ninja" key={ninjaList.id}>
            <div>Name : {ninjan.name}</div>
            <div>Age: {ninjan.age}</div>
            <div>Belt:{ninjan.belt}</div>
        </div>
        )
    })
    return(
        <div className="ninja-list">
            {ninjaList}
        </div>
    )
}


export default Ninjas
```

Comment: Just call the function ninjaList

Comment: can you clarify??

Comment: I meant use `{ninja list()}` instead of just `{ninja list}`

Answer (score 0):

you should try it like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Ninjas = ({list}) => {
   
    const ninjaList = list.map( (ninjan , index)=> {
        return (
            <div className="ninja" key={index}>
            <div>Name : {ninjan.name}</div>
            <div>Age: {ninjan.age}</div>
            <div>Belt:{ninjan.belt}</div>
        </div>
        )
    })
    return(
        <div className="ninja-list">
            {()=>ninjaList()}
        </div>
    )
}


export default Ninjas
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a typo in this line:

```
<div className="ninja" key={ninjaList.id}>
```

You are referencing to the list not to the list element.

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code.

```
 const ninjan = [ { id: 1, name: 'adasdasdasd' },{ id: 2, name: '123' }] ;

  const ninjaList = ninjan.map( (ninjan)=> { 
    return ( 
      <div className="ninja" key={ninjan.id}>
      <div>Name : {ninjan.name}</div> 
      <div>Id : {ninjan.id}</div> 
  </div>
    )
}) 
    return (
      <div className="content">
        
       { Object.keys(ninjaList).length >0 && 
       ninjaList
       }
        
      </div>
    );
```